# How to check if MediaPlayer is released()?

Tags: android

I want to check if MediaPlayer is released - how to check it? I found that isPlaying generate exception instead of false - it is complicated how to do it in simple way.

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it through the MediaPlayer class itself.

Easiest thing to do is global variable that gets set to `true` upon creation and reset.  It get set to `false` on release.

```
boolean mIsPlayerRelease = true;

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(myContext, soundId); // ready to play
mIsPlayerRelease = false;

....
mediaPlayer.reset();   // ready to play again
mIsPlayerRelease = false;

....

mediaPlayer.release(); // can't be played until release.
mIsPlayerRelease = true;
```

**EDIT:**

You can fix the blocking issue by placing the creation in an `AsyncTask` and setting the variable on completion.

```
private class MediaCreator extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

   WeakReference<Context> mCtx;

   public MediaCreator(Context ctx) {
      mCtx = new WeakReference(ctx);
   }

   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackgroind(Integer.... params) {
      final Context ctx = mCtx.get();
      if(ctx == null || params == null || params.length == 0) {
         return false;
      }

      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, params[0];
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
      if(success) {
          mIsPlayerRelease = false;
      } else {
          mIsPlayerRelease = true;
      }
   }
}
```

You can put this class in whatever class is handling `mediaPlayer`.  Start it with

```
MediaCreator creator = new MediaCreator(myContext);
creator.execute(R.id.mySoundId);
```

The method `doInBackground` will create and buffer the media player on a separate thread. It will return once created and `onPostExecute()` will be called on the main thread setting the boolean to `false` if the player was created.

Comment: It looks good - is mIsPlayerRelease not need to be volatile if listeners is used what about mulitthreading?

Comment: Is it mean that activity and player.setOnCompletionListener is working in the same thread always - if defined in same class?

Comment: Sorry.  My last comment was wrong.  `start()` is not inherently blocking, though the creation could be when buffering the media.

Comment: The listener runs on whatever thread you created it in.  If you created the OnCompletionListener on a separate thread than the main thread, then you will need to make it volatile.

Comment: So you need to add volatile variable to accept your question or some other Android blocking code? I will accept answer if you fix blocking.

Comment: Let refine finally is "The listener runs on whatever thread you created it in." == "The listener runs on __which thread__ you created it in." - whetever is little unclear to me.